# Is this an acceptable way to approach a curl fail in a scrape? What would be the dry approach?

Tags: php, curl

I'm scraping a few pages. Now and then curl throws a connection reset error. I'm guessing it has to do with bad packets.

I've written a function which tries to curl the uri, and if it fails, to try again after a sleep, then try one more time. As you can see, I'm repeating some code there. If's inside if's. Is that normal / acceptable? I know sometimes internet can drop out for minutes, so maybe I'd like it to try not 1 or 2 times, but 20 times for example. What would be a more dry approach? i.e. while curl_errno is true, then keep repeating x times?

```
// {all the headers and options here}

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    sleep(1);

    // try again
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        sleep(2);

        // try again
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch)) {
            // stop trying, save to fails db for later debug
        }
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recursion** comes in handy in this case:

```
function loadData($ch, $retries) {
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        if ($retries > 0) {
            sleep(1);

            // try again
            return loadData($ch, $retries - 1);
        } else {
            // stop trying, save to fails db for later debug
            return FAIL;
        }
    } else return $result;
}

$result = loadData($ch, 20) // retry up to 20 times
```

Comment: Should be called inception! Brilliant. Learned a lot from this, thank you.

Comment: Recursion seems like overkill, what's wrong with a plain ol' loop?

Comment: @Addy Nothing, really. But recursion is not really any more complicated than a loop and in cases like this sometimes more clear in my opinion.

Comment: A loop should usually be preferred over recursion when possible. Each recursion is going to allocate its own stack, which causes overhead. Also, if you have to refactor the parameters in the code you want repeated, recursion adds complexity in refactoring that is relatively simple with a loop (ie. what if you want to pass another param to `curl_exec`, then suddenly you have to add another param to `loadData`).